# Window decorations, e.g., the minimise, maximise and close buttons are oversized

Tags: ubuntu-mate, window-decoration

Sometimes when I turn on my laptop the window decorations are blown,

[image]

This only happens on/while connected to an external monitor whose resolution is lower than my laptop's which is 4K. I can fix it by changing the window decorations or window borders to something and back to what they were. This re-scales them correctly.

I have had this issue since I installed the OS. It is Ubuntu Mate 20.04.1 LTS with MATE Desktop Environment 1.24.0. The theme is Arch Dark. It is getting a little annoying having to toggle the decorations to scale them correctly, does anyone know how to fix them permanently?

Comment: For more productive result please ask on http://ubuntu-mate.community/ .

Comment: [Here we go.](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/window-decorations-e-g-the-minimise-maximise-and-close-buttons-are-oversized/23397?u=simurgh9)